# Problems verifying signature of OSX app for GateKeeper (Sierra) ["the code is valid but does not seem to be an app"]

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I am building my app and signing with a valid code signing certificate (Developer ID Application...) via:

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application:..." <binary>
```

My .app/Contents/MacOS folder has a natively compiled binary that I execute from within the cocoa app. I'm also signing this binary using the same codesign command.

When I try to verify the signature of the different components using 'spctl' I get this for my main cocoa app:

```
accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: <redacted> Inc. (<redacted>)
```

When I run the same on the secondary binary I get:

```
rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)
origin=Developer ID Application: <redacted> Inc. (<redacted>)
```

I can't find anything via google today on the string 'the code is valid but does not seem to be an app'.

I'm not sure what to infer from that statement or how to proceed. Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40295328/5971390

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS Gatekeeper blocking signed command line tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811791/mac-os-gatekeeper-blocking-signed-command-line-tool)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was bundling with go-astilectron-bundler and in my case adding

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

to **Info.plist** file solved the problem.

https://github.com/asticode/go-astilectron-bundler/pull/30/files