# Mac OS Gatekeeper blocking signed command line tool

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I have a "command line tool" target (not an App bundle) in Xcode that is being blocked by Gatekeeper. I've used this tool for years as a simple installer for my PostCheck Address Book plugin.

In 2012 I signed the tool with my Apple Developer ID so that it wouldn't be blocked by Gatekeeper and all was well for a while. I've now noticed that with macOS Sierra (10.12) that it's now being blocked, and during testing I've also found that it's blocked by 10.11.6 as well. (When I say blocked, I mean the user has to right-click on it and choose 'open' instead of being given the option in the warning dialog.) It still works fine with 10.11.2! – If I recall, Mac OS X 10.11.4 had a bug that blocked non-app bundles even if they were signed, but I think that problem was fixed in 10.11.5. Maybe it's related?

I've tried re-compiling and re-signing the executable with Xcode 8 under Sierra. I tried embedding an Info.plist in the binary (which I hadn't done before). I've tried archiving rather than just "building" in case it was an issue with debug vs. release configurations. I've spent two days searching methods for validating my executable is signed properly, seemingly with conflicting results…

There's this:

```
codesign --verify --verbose <executable> 
<executable>: valid on disk
<executable>: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

And this:

```
spctl --assess --verbose <executable> 
<executable>: rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)
source=matched cdhash
```

And this:

```
spctl -a -v --raw <executable> 
<executable>: accepted
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>assessment:authority</key>
    <dict>
        <key>assessment:authority:flags</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>assessment:authority:source</key>
        <string>allowed cdhash</string>
        <key>assessment:authority:weak</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>assessment:cserror</key>
    <integer>-67002</integer>
    <key>assessment:remote</key>
    <true/>
    <key>assessment:verdict</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I suppose part of my problem is I don't know what a command line executable is supposed to look like after being signed with a valid Apple Developer ID. And I also don't know if it's a macOS problem that I can't do anything about anyway. It's also extremely difficult to Google for both command line tools and code signing problems and find something actually related to code signing a command line Unix executable.

I appreciate any insight into what might be going on here. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the `--strict` option with `codesign`. Also, try using the `-t open` option with `spctl`, since double-clicking an executable doesn't really execute it directly, it passes it to Terminal as a document and Terminal executes the path as a command. That might address the "does not seem to be an app" issue. You can also specify `-v` multiple times to increase verbosity. Use `--ignore-cache` just to be sure you're assessing the file fresh.

Comment: FWIW, error cserror -67002 is errSecCSNotAppLike (which is probably not a huge surprise).  I "fixed" this by creating an app bundle with what essentially a command line tool in it and signing the bundle. I could then run the command line tool, and just had to reference it as foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo. Not a great user experience, but works for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to answer my questions, but in case anyone comes across this same problem:

**The solution is to distribute the command line tool on a signed disk image rather than in a zip file.**

I ended up testing back to 10.11.4 and confirmed that's when the trouble began. (I must have been testing it improperly back then.) OS X simply blocks double-clicking a Unix Command Line Tool, no matter how I sign it. It's probably for the best as most command line tools will be run from within Terminal.app.

For Sierra, it turned out I needed the signed DMG anyway to get around the new Path Randomization feature of Gatekeeper.

Comment: It seems that "notarization", as of Catalina, may revive this issue zombie-like from the grave, and in this case, it seems (in my case, at any rate) that making the executable part of a signed and notarized DMG file may not solve the problem.

Comment: self-answer for posterity; in my case, the problem may have been that the executable loads another library, and so even though both are notarized, running the executable that loads the library is a no-no.

Comment: I too found that Catalina will block a command line tool that links against a .dylib with relative loader paths (i.e. `otool -L /path/to/libFoo.dylib` outputs `@executable_path` somewhere because the library was built with `DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE=@executable_path`). Possible workarounds include: 1) Remove the relative loader path (Specify `/usr/local/bin` instead of `@executable_path`) 2) Package and install them from a signed .pkg to avoid the quarantine flag being set when users download your distribution, 3) Distribute the executable and library in a bundle and run the CLI tool from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was bundling with go-astilectron-bundler and in my case adding

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

to **Info.plist** file solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug in macOS Catalina 10.15.3 and earlier (fixed in 10.15.4) wherein a notarized command line app that links against a .dylib outside of its bundle (and command line apps are typically not in a bundle) will still fail Gatekeeper checks that trigger when the quarantine** flag is set on the command line executable.

To workaround the problem, Apple DTS recommends:

> The easiest workaround is to sign your tool with both the hardened runtime and library validation flags.
>
> That is, change your invocation of `codesign` from this:
>
> `% codesign -s …stuff… -o runtime …stuff… helloworld`
>
> to this:
>
> `% codesign -s …stuff… -o runtime,library …stuff… helloworld`
>
> Explicitly setting the library flag disables this Gatekeeper check and allows your tool to run on macOS 10.15.{0,1,2,3}. Please make a note to remove this flag once 10.15.4 is released and widely adopted.

**The quarantine flag is set whenever you receive a file via internet download or AirDrop (but not via network File Sharing or iCloud Drive), according to https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/24/airdrop-and-quarantine-flags/